# Jquery Slider appears in weird positions sometimes

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, wordpress

I have a problem with my jquery slider. Every now and then the slider opens in a weird position just like on this screenshot here: http://pixelcravers.ca/screens/slider-problem.png
I noticed when I right click on the container area of the slider and go to inspect element in Google Chrome the slider moves right back in its correct position.

My website's link is http://pixelcravers.ca

Comment: I don't see a slider in the image you posted.

Comment: Not sure what you meant but I re-uploaded the screenshot now to showcase the problem a little better. (PS: There is only one layer in the slider which is the world map.)

Comment: That's not a slider. Here's a link to let you know what others think you mean when you say "slider": http://jqueryui.com/slider/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like he means this slider 
http://dev7studios.com/nivo-slider/

So you'd have to evaluate why there's an issue with the CSS being loaded inconstantly.